# Parking rules for motorbikes in Rome, Italy

Tags: italy, transportation, motorcycles

I'm going to travel Italy by a motorbike. This is my first travel long distance using this kind of transportation.

- What are the parking rules and norms in Italy (especially, in Rome) for bikes?
- Should I use special parking lots, or I can leave it as long as it doesn't mess with other vehicles? How about on the pavement?

Comment: This really depends on where you are going. In general motorbikes park for free, unless you park in a paid-parking area. Rome is parking anarchy in general so it'll depend on where you go and how long you stay for. In principle parking on the pavement is forbidden and you should get a ticket. In practice I have had this happen once in 15 years of driving motorbikes in Italy. I am not advocating breaking the law here, I am just sharing my experience.

Comment: Um, tongue-in-cheek answer here, but does Italy actually have any parking rules or norms? Even if they do, I don't think they're ever enforced. Particularly the further south you go the more likely you are to find people parked wherever and however they really darn feel like it. Obviously I wouldn't suggest such behavior, but that's what you'll see from the locals.

Comment: When it comes to blue (paid) stripes, metropolitan police is happy about enforcing

Answer (score 3):

From [this motorbike guide](https://www.motosicura.it/legge-e-normative/driving-motorcycle-in-italy/):

> ## Parking Areas
>
> **Zona Blue**: parking lines are painted in blue denoting either “pay and display” (pay for a ticket from the dispensing machine and display it clearly in the front windscreen) or display a blue parking disc set to the time at parking. Blue discs are available from banks, tourist offices, tobacconists and post offices. Always be aware of the maximum time allowed and confirm if payment is necessary as many blue spaces are free at lunchtime and in the evenings.
>
> **White Lines**: mark the parking bays indicate that it is free parking.
>
> **Yellow Areas**: indicate disabled parking (with a disabled permit/Blue Badge) or delivery zones

[Another motorbike/scooter](http://romethesecondtime.blogspot.com/2011/01/parking-scooter-in-rome.html?m=1) guide provides additional information:

> Parking between two parked cars is fine, but only if you leave enough space for the cars to clear your bike or, if the cars are parked side-by-side, enough space for car drivers and passengers to enter and exit. In rural areas, one can park on the side of the road with impunity.